# Remove + (Plus Sign) from URL when displayed in page using PHP

Tags: php

I've created a function so I can display a specific part of a URL:

```
function PageName() {
return substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+10,strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")-4);
}
```

This will allow me to show **The+Title** if the URL is domain.com/my-pages/The+Title/go/

It works perfectly if the title is one word, but in the above example it is two words with a + sign.

I've tried to add **str_replace("+"," ",PageName)** at the end to replace the plus sign with an empty space, but doesn't seem to work:

```
function PageName() {
return substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+10,strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")-4,str_replace("+"," ",PageName));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing the third argument to `str_replace`.

Comment: My bad. Updated the original question. It's there but doesn't work still.

Comment: `str_replace("+"," ",PageName())` - you need to call the function.  I would actually do `urldecode(PageName())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For decoding the `+` you would better use `urldecode`, because that is what you are doing: decoding the URL format.

Furthermore, the `+10` you have in the expression makes your solution not very reusable. Maybe you know at which position (counting forward slashes) that title is positioned at in the URL. In that case this might be more useful as a solution:

```
// $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "domain.com/my-pages/The+Title/go/";

function pageName($url) {
    return urldecode(explode("/", $url)[2]); // adapt the 2 to what you need.
}

echo pageName($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Comment: Genius! Works like a charm. Good note.